# High wait time Before getting the response or the context deadline exceeded go-micro

Tags: go, microservices, rpc, go-micro

I have a grpc client written using go-micro, which is making a call to grpc microservice which is further connecting to elastic search to get the search result.

My web service where I am creating my grpc client and the grpc service making connection to elasticsearch  are registering to same registry consul (enabled for TLS configuration).

But when client tries to call the grpc service sometimes the request gets successful but sometimes I get the context timeout exceeded.

I am not sure whether consul is taking time to return the service information or it is the connection issue with elastic search or there is an issue with grpc client .

Please help I am stuck on this issue for so long. Thanks in advance.

I tried changing the connection pool size for my grpc client.
I tried increasing registry ttl , registry timeout but nothing works.

consul "github.com/micro/go-plugins/registry/consul"

```
// my registry options 
func registryOptions(ops *registry.Options) {
        //ops.Timeout = time.Second * 30  
        ops.Secure = true
        ops.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
        ops.Addrs = []string{consulReg}
        log.Println("registry options : ", ops)
}
```

If I uncomment the timeout I get consul watch error which while service health check (request timeout) (maybe coz of blocking query).

```
// this is my web service  

reg = consul.NewRegistry(registryOptions)
                // reg := consul.NewRegistry(registryOptions)
                //reg.Watch()
                service := web.NewService(
                        web.Name("lena"),
                        web.Address(serverPort),
                        web.Advertise(advertize),
                        //web.RegisterTTL(time.Second*30),
                        //web.RegisterInterval(time.Second*10),
                        web.Registry(reg),
                )
```

I am also using --registry=consul

This is my grpc client that is calling elastic search service

```
import(
grpcCl "github.com/micro/go-micro/client/grpc"
 "github.com/micro/go-micro/client/selector"
cache "github.com/micro/go-micro/client/selector/registry"
)

Client: grpcCl.NewClient(mclient.PoolSize(100),mclient.RequestTimeout(60*time.Second),mclient.Retries(3),mclient.Selector(cache.NewSelector(selector.Registry(reg))),mclient.Registry(reg)
```

This is my elastic search client -

```
import "github.com/olivere/elastic"

elastic.NewClient(
                elastic.SetURL(es.Host1, es.Host2, es.Host3))
```

Grpc client should get the timely response from grpc service but I am getting context deadline exceeded

Comment: Can you instrument your microservice with logging to determine where exactly the problem is? Try turning deadlines off completely on your client and logging how long the request to elasticsearch takes.

Comment: yaa have put logs everywhere and I got to know that it is taking time to discover my grpc service. Sometimes it discovers fast and sometimes it takes lot of time.